# Correct way to get size of SwiftUI view and write it to Model

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have some model:

```
public struct someModel{
    var someContent: CGSize
}
```

I have someView:

```
struct StatusEntryView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model : someModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([Axis.Set.horizontal, Axis.Set.vertical]) {
            GeometryReader { gr in
                VStack{
                    ForEach(self.model.hunks){ hunk in
                        HunkView(hunk: hunk)
                    }
                }

            self.model.contentSize = gr.size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what is correct way to get ScrollView's actual content size and write it into model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `GeometryReader` but not in that place, here it is

```swift
ScrollView([Axis.Set.horizontal, Axis.Set.vertical]) {
    VStack{
        ForEach(self.model.hunks){ hunk in
            HunkView(hunk: hunk)
        }
    }.background(GeometryReader { gr in
        self.model.contentSize = gr.size // might be needed wrap in async
        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    })
}
```

**Note:** pay attention on comment in code, `cause now it is not clear how you're going to use that size, but if you'll right ahead from there change layout of views then it will be needed to wrap in`DispatchQueue.main.async {}` to avoid view update cycling.

Comment: will check a little bit later and mark your answer as correct after the check. Thanks a lot, Asperi